# How to use parameter 'key' without built-in function?

Tags: python, parameters, mergesort

I am studying python with book, have a question while defining **Merge Sort** code.
Based on the conditions in the book, I defined code successfully

Question is about the use of Parameter key.
I have learned how to use the Parameter key before.
As far as i know, key is function that change Comparison Criteria
For Example, It can be used as follows. I learned.

```
def selection_sort(xs, key=lambda x: x):
    ss = []
    while xs != []:
        smallest = min(xs, key=key)
        xs.remove(smallest)
        ss.append(smallest)

    return ss 

# Execution value of selection_sort
> selection_sort([4, -2, 3, -1, 5])
> [-2, -1, 3, 4, 5]
> selection_sort([4, -2, 3, -1, 5], key = abs)
> [-1, -2, 3, 4, 5]
> selection_sort([4, -2, 3, -1, 5], key= lambda x: -x)
> [5, 4, 3, -1, -2]
```

Below is part of my Merge sort code.
The parameter key I know is to use as a parameter value for the built-in function.
Then can't I use the key in the code below without built-in function?
I wonder where i can put the key to use changing sorting conditions.

```
def merge(left,right, key = lambda x: x): # A function that merge sort two list
        ss = []
        while not (left == [] or right == []):
            if left[0] <= right[0]:
                ss.append( left[0] ) 
                left = left[1:]
            else:
                ss.append( right[0] ) 
                right = right[1:]
    
        ss.extend(left)  
        ss.extend(right)
        return ss

# Execution value of merge
merge([18, 23, 32], [7, 11, 55, 99])
> [7, 11, 18, 23, 32, 55, 99]
```

Answer (score 2):

The Python `key` function to the built-in `sort` is intended to be applied immediately before performing any comparisons.

```
if key(left[0]) <= key(right[0]):
    ...
```

Comment: I think I've learned how to approach, thank you

Comment: This is not actually how `sorted` and `list.sort` use their `key` functions. They only call the function once per item, not twice per comparison (which is a much larger number). This is much more like how the `cmp` function you could pass to the sorting functions worked back in Python 2, it was called for every comparison.

Answer (score 2):

To efficiently use a `key` parameter, you should apply it just once to each object in the list. You keep the returned value around, attached to the data item, and sort based on the returned value rather than the original object.

Before `sorted` had a `key` parameter, there was an idiom called "Decorate-Sort-Undecorate" that transformed a list before sorting it, and then reversed the transformation on the sorted list to get the original objects back:

```
def my_sort(data, key=lambda x: x):
    decorated_data = [(key(x), i, x) for i, x in enumerate(data)]   # decorate

    # replace this with your sorting logic
    sorted_results = sorted(decorated_data)                         # sort

    undecorated_results = [tup[2] for tup in sorted_results]        # undecorate
    return undecorated_results
```

The decoration step turns each value in `data` into a 3-tuple, starting with the value returned by the key function, and then by an integer (to break ties, which might be necessary if some items should sort as if they were equal, and the objects themselves are not comparable). The item comes last in the tuple, and so we get index 2 when we need to undecorate and get just a list of the items for our output.